# Eloquent - id is blank even though object isn't empty

Tags: php, eloquent

I'm having an issue with Eloquent. I am returning an object that contains data but when trying to access the `id` of the returned field it's blank.

Here's some example code:

```
public function activateMobile($token)
{
    /*
     * Get mobile activation row matching $token
     */
    $activation = $this->ci->ActivationRepository->getMobileActivationByToken($token);

    /*
     * Does it exist?
     */
    if(empty($activation)) {
        return false;
    }

    die($activation);
}
```

And here's the model:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MobileVerification extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'mobile_verification';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\MyApp\Models\User');
    }
}
```

For examples sake I used `die` to print the value of the object in string form:

```
{"id":7,"user_id":24,"token":"68gb","is_used":0,"verified_at":null,"created_at":"2016-11-28 18:53:52","updated_at":"2016-11-28 18:53:52"}
```

As you can see the `id` is there.

But, if I replace the `die` with `die($activation->id)` its blank. Yet, if I do `die($activation->token)` that's visible.

Why is the `id` returning blank?

Comment: Have you verified the visibility of `id`?

Comment: @HalfCrazed updated post with the model

Comment: Just to verify, can you try `var_dump($activation->getVisible())` (I'm assuming `$activation` is a `model` at this point)

Comment: `die((string) $activation->id)` or `var_dump($activation->id); die();` might work.

Comment: I can do `$activation['id']` (thanks chrisml on #laravel). But still not sure why I can't access with `$activation->id`. I can access the token with `$activation->token`

Comment: @HalfCrazed yeah it's the model. And an empty array when doing `var_dump($activation->getVisible())`

Comment: @Nick `(string) $activation->id` works. This is so weird.

Comment: @BugHunterUK not really, passing an integer to `die()` doesn't print anything, it gets used as the exit code instead: http://php.net/die and http://php.net/exit

Comment: @Nick but `die` was used as an example. If I pass `$activation->id` to a method it's still blank. I can see it using xdebug. Also if I do `$activation->user->id` that works fine.